# File system is not writable

Tags: php, drupal-7, filesystems, file-permissions

I installed Drupal 7 in a web host successfully. 
After installing a module, I got an error errors and and status report gave me this error message:

```
File system Not writable
The directory /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php does not exist.
You may need to set the correct directory at the file system settings page or
change the current directory's permissions so that it is writable.
```

I check the permissions for `(sites/default/files)` and it has **755** permissions and I change it to **777** but nothing happened so I return it back.

I have the following setting for `(Home » Administration » Configuration » Media):`

```
Public file system path
sites/default/files

Temporary directory
/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php
```

and here is the error I am getting:

```
Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://fileDyFbDg) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in file_unmanaged_save_data() (line 1898 of /home/imamus/public_html/includes/file.inc).
The file could not be created.
Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://fileeTFMpl) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in file_unmanaged_save_data() (line 1898 of /home/imamus/public_html/includes/file.inc).
The file could not be created.
Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://fileuB8Tdu) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in file_unmanaged_save_data() (line 1898 of /home/imamus/public_html/includes/file.inc).
The file could not be created.
Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://filea1KYXG) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in file_unmanaged_save_data() (line 1898 of /home/imamus/public_html/includes/file.inc).
The file could not be created.
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I check the permissions for (sites/default/files) and it has 755 permissions and I change it to 777 but nothing happened so I return it back.

do the same for `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php`

Comment: where is this located?
my website is not hosted locally.

Comment: it is an absoulte path and thus located at the top level (file system root) aka "/", then Applications, then MAMP, then tmp, then php. You might want to change it to something that actually exists and the fix the permissions. --- everything on the server of course.

Comment: Thank you for your help...I created  /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php in the file system root but still getting error also I created in /public_html where is my website files located but still getting same error.

Comment: do you have shell access to the server? what does `ls -la  /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php` say?

Comment: you probably created pubic_html in your home directory (probably: `/home/imamus`) that is different from the root directory (always: `/`). did you possibly create `/home/imamus/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php`? please do a `ls` for that one as well.

Comment: I created it on /home/imamus/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php and link this /home/imamus/public_html/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php where is my website hosted. my home dirctory is (/home/imamus). I cannot move up because I have no permission from my web host. I am accessing my home directory either from cpanel or filezilla. both location did not work with me.

Comment: in the config (Home » Administration » Configuration » Media), add /home/imamus in front of /Applications to fix the absolute path or remove the / from /Applications to make it a relative path (relative to... hmm difficult to say, so use the other method first). Either way, make sure, that it points to a folder that actually exists and has proper permissions. Something starting with /Application will never be in your home.

Comment: I removed the / from /Applications to make it a relative path as you advised and it works. thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

This reply is for non-windows sites : 
In my case, the sites/default/files/ folder was set to 775 ( not a good idea to have it set to 777 )
I had to delete the following folder :

```
rm -rf /tmp/devel_themer/
```

Then it worked !

Answer (score 0):

The error happens, because your temporary directory is not writable by your web server user.

You may check that in admin panel by going to *Reports* and *Status report* at: `/admin/reports/status`.

To fix it, you've to got to *File system* in *Configuration* (at `/admin/config/media/file-system`), then change your *temporary directory* to point to your writable directory. If that's correct, then make you set the right permission on it, e.g.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php
```

and the same for default files folder:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 sites/default/files
```

#### Drush

If you're using `drush`, check which folder is set currently by:

```
drush vget file_temporary_path
```

Then to fix it, try:

```
drush vset file_temporary_path /tmp
```

Here are default temporary directories:

- OS X: `/private/tmp`, for MAMP: `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php`
- Linux/Unix: `/tmp`