# How to get rid of: Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://): failed to open stream:"DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open"?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, file-permissions

I get this message from Drupal:

> Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://file8vyLsO): failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in file_unmanaged_save_data() (line 1900 of /home/donatelo/public_html/thenameofthesite.com/includes/file.inc).
>
> The file could not be created.

I don't know what I did to cause this, can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File system is not writable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510374/file-system-is-not-writable)

Answer (score 3):

Check File system configuration on Admin side. You need to create tmp folder make it grand 777 access, and add tmp folder path it to 'File system' configuration.